# when using accelerate fsdp, from_pretrained loaded error weight of CLIPVisionModel at one process,traing with nan

Tags: pytorch, nlp, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, accelerate

when using accelerate fsdp, from_pretrained loaded error weight of CLIPVisionModel at one process,traing with nan

I try to use accelerate fsdp at 2 A40 gpus, but the trainning with nan loss and -inf weight.

by debug the code,I find that CLIPVisionModel(loading at the **init** beginning and not the trainning model) weight are wrong,

at one process I find the wright CLIPVisionModel weight:
tensor([0.3311, 0.0032, 0.1610,  ..., 2.1922, 0.0050, 0.0039],)

and the other process, the CLIPVisionModel weight is wrong:
tensor([-1.9921e-04,  4.5673e-41, -1.9921e-04,  ...,  0.0000e+00,0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],)

and the wrong CLIPVisionModel weight case the hidden parameters are inf or nan ,and the trainning loss is nan

this is my loading code :

class SLlamaModel(LlamaModel):
config_class = SConfig

```
def __init__(self, config: LlamaConfig, mm_vision_tower=None, mm_hidden_size=None):
    super(SLlamaModel, self).__init__(config)

    if hasattr(config, "mm_vision_tower"):
        # HACK: for FSDP
        self.vision_tower = CLIPVisionModel.from_pretrained(config.mm_vision_tower)

    if hasattr(config, "use_mm_proj"):
        self.mm_projector = nn.Linear(config.mm_hidden_size, config.hidden_size)
```

config.mm_vision_tower = path to clip-vit-large-patch14

self.vision_tower = CLIPVisionModel.from_pretrained(config.mm_vision_tower)

here is my fsdp config:

- compute_environment: LOCAL_MACHINE
- distributed_type: FSDP
- downcast_bf16: 'no'
- fsdp_config:
  fsdp_auto_wrap_policy: TRANSFORMER_BASED_WRAP
  fsdp_backward_prefetch_policy: BACKWARD_PRE
  fsdp_forward_prefetch: true
  fsdp_offload_params: true
  fsdp_sharding_strategy: 1
  fsdp_state_dict_type: FULL_STATE_DICT
  fsdp_sync_module_states: true
  fsdp_transformer_layer_cls_to_wrap: LlamaDecoderLayer
  fsdp_use_orig_params: true
- machine_rank: 0
- main_training_function: main
- mixed_precision: bf16
- num_machines: 1
- num_processes: 2
- rdzv_backend: static
- same_network: true
- tpu_env: []
- tpu_use_cluster: false
- tpu_use_sudo: false
- use_cpu: false

two A40 gpus: 48G VRAM per

- `Accelerate` version: 0.21.0
- Platform: Linux-5.4.0-90-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
- Python version: 3.10.12
- Numpy version: 1.25.1
- PyTorch version (GPU?): 2.0.1+cu117 (False)
- PyTorch XPU available: False
- PyTorch NPU available: False
- System RAM: 755.74 GB

I debug the whole code and find the weight error from the beginning when loading by from_pretrained  and not other code error.I try to  using test = CLIPVisionModel.from_pretrained("model path") at debug when the code run to loading line and still got error weight

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into the same issue. Although I still don't understand how this happens, upgrading transformers to version 4.37.2 solved it for me.